# strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series time series convert

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I use datetime to read time from json,
the code for single time works well,

```
 import datetime
 data=datetime.datetime.strptime('Apr 12, 2018', '%b %d, Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

However, when I try to apply it into data frame, I have error.

```
 df_newtime=datetime.datetime.strptime(old_df['oldDate'],'%b %d, %Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

the error is `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series`

Comment: `old_df['oldDate']` is a column of the dataframe. You need to loop over it, you can't just pass it directly to a non-Pandas function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

**Method 1:**

Here we pass a string to the function using `map`

```
list(map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%b %d, %Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), old_df['oldDate']))
```

**Method 2:**

Here we pass a series

```
pd.to_datetime(old_df['oldDate'], format='%b %d, %Y')
```

Answer (score 3):

`old_df['oldDate']` will return the column containing the dates, which is a series.

You can solve this issue by using the .apply function in pandas to apply a function to every row of a dataframe. See [here](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations/classes/pandas%20columns%20and%20functions/apply-a-function-to-every-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe/)

```
def date_convert(date_to_convert):
     return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_to_convert, '%b %d, 
     %Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

new_df['new_date'] = old_df['oldDate'].apply(date_convert)
```